# Borland can't compile. What is going on? I can't even get started

Tags: c++, compilation, borland-c++

Consider:

```
cd C:\BORLAND\BCC55\BIN
bcc32 hello.cpp
```

Output:

```
Borland C++ 5.5.1 for Win32 Copyright (c) 1993, 2000 Borland
hello.cpp:
Error E2209 hello.cpp 2: Unable to open include file 'iostream'
Error E2090 hello.cpp 6: Qualifier 'std' is not a class or namespace name in fun
ction main()
Error E2379 hello.cpp 6: Statement missing ; in function main()
*** 3 errors in Compile ***
```

I read [the instructions at Embarcadero](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/21205). Now, it says...

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main(void)
{
    cout << "Hello." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
cd C:\Borland\BCC55\Bin\MySource
bcc32 hello.cpp
```

Output:

```
Borland C++ 5.5.1 for Win32 Copyright (c) 1993, 2000 Borland
hello.cpp:
Error E2209 hello.cpp 1: Unable to open include file 'iostream.h'
Error E2451 hello.cpp 4: Undefined symbol 'cout' in function main()
Error E2451 hello.cpp 4: Undefined symbol 'end' in function main()
Error E2379 hello.cpp 4: Statement missing ; in function main()
*** 4 errors in Compile ***
```

Comment: Show us some code, and by the way, why on earth you're using Borland C++? Switch to Visual C++ 2008 Express or g++.

Comment: ouch, just googled Borland 5.5. That thing is *ancient*. Don't use it, there are plenty of free alternatives. Microsoft's Visual C++ Express is free, and an excellent compiler + IDE. And it's simple to set up and use. Alternatively, you could go with the Windows port of GCC.

Comment: This is cool as all hell.  This was my first compiler!

Comment: I don't get what is up with all this borland compiler bashing. It may be old but it's still one of the fastest damn compilers out there. It still generates smaller and faster code than gcc port mingw and cygwin -- not to mention much faster compiler time...

And it's also very small and lightweight as well, for those of us that don't want to download gigantic IDE's and other stuff with it.

Comment: Please remove the C++ tag from this question, as whatever you are going to produce with that thing, will not be C++.

Comment: @VictorT.: yeah, but it just can not compile C++ ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seriously, you're going to keep having troubles if you continue to use Borland's compiler. It's free from their computer *museum* for a reason - it's ancient. The copyright line itself should be proof enough of that:

> Borland C++ 5.5.1 for Win32 Copyright (c) 1993, 2000 Borland

Do you *really* want a compiler that hasn't been updated in decades, one that the standard has long since left behind?

It's the compiler you get if you're interested in vintage computing stuff, in the same league as people with TRS-80 and Apple II emulators :-)

Download Microsoft Visual C++ Express and install it. It's as free (as in cost) as the Borland one and substantially more up to date. See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/product/) for the product page.

Or there are many other more up-to-date development  tools you can get for free as well, such as `gcc`, `Code::Blocks` and so forth.

Comment: `Code::Blocks` is not a compiler, it is an IDE.

Comment: On my technical university we use BCC 3.1 :/ It's 2014 now.

Comment: @Kacper, then your uni is deficient for teaching modern C++. It may be fine for language basics but a lot has changed in the last 15-odd years.

Comment: We use it to compile hybrid C and Assembly for Intel 8086 applications.

Comment: Re *"if you continue to use Borland's compiler"*: [It may](https://www.quora.com/Why-should-I-use-GCC-and-Clang-over-Turbo-C/answer/Paulina-Jonu%C5%A1ait%C4%97) [be forced](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-bitter-truths-about-engineering-in-India/answer/Adhokshaj-Mishra). ***Everything is frozen in time***. Another example is *[Wren & Martin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark#comment206109_4645)*.

Answer (score 3):

The first error has a resolution in the [installation instructions](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/21205).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick to Borland products you can install [Turbo C++](http://www.turboexplorer.com/cpp). I'm talking about the 2006 Turbo C++ part of the "[Turbo Explorer](http://www.turboexplorer.com/)" effort to bring back some of the popularity of the 90's Turbo C++.

They brag with "Turbo C++ contains support for the industry standard ANSI C and ISO/ANSI C++ languages and libraries. Turbo C++ also includes the Dinkumware C++ runtime libraries and support for the popular Boost library."

I think that a 2006 implementation should be decent enough, somehow not so popular like Visual Studio Express 2005/2008.

Regarding the compilation problems, one must fiddle with the two configuration files found in the bin directory (in this case C:\BORLAND\BCC55\BIN), namely bcc32.cfg and ilink32.cfg. The compiler cannot find the iostream.h file.

Comment: By the way, those links no longer allows you to get C++/Delphi/Explorer. They state they're unavailable but let you download a trial of more recent software.

Answer (score 1):

**Create two files inside C:\Borland\bcc55\bin**

Edit its information with following:

In file **BCC32.cfg**

```
      -I"c:\Borland\Bcc55\include"

      -L"c:\Borland\Bcc55\lib"
```

Create another file with name **ILINK32.cfg**

```
      -L"c:\Borland\Bcc55\lib"
```

Now use your compiler and don't forget to add

```
      #include<iostream>

      using namespace std;
```

in the heading section.

Answer (score 0):

"iostream.h" is not a standard C++ header. Some compilers provide it for legacy support, but you should always use just "iostream" instead. The main difference between the legacy and the standard one is the `std` namespace. To have a compliant version of your example, it would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; // import the contents of the std namespace
                     // into the global namespace

int main() {
    cout << "Hello." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: indeed, he should definitely get a compiler made this decade :-P.